# Deleting Line from Plot

Tags: r, graph, plot, line

Just a quick question: I'm trying to plot a graph in R and I have covered how to do that, but how do I delete a line I have just created? For instance:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6.7, 7, 8, 10 )
y <- c(40, 30, 10, 20, 53, 20, 10, 5)

plot(x,y,main="X vs Y", xlab="X", ylab="Y")

lines(x,y,col="black",lty="dotted")
```

This produces a nice graph. However, say I would like to delete the line I created previously (or perhaps the points as well?!) how should I go about doing it?

Comment: R uses a pen+paper model for graphing, so once something is drawn on the device, its there until you start over with a blank device.

Comment: there are hacks like re-drawing the same line with the background color (`lines(x,y,col="white",lty="dotted")`) -- but they're fragile (e.g. depend on drawing against a white background, etc.)

Comment: Thanks Ben and joran. This pen+paper model becomes a prroblem if I have two or more plots on the same graph, as re-drawing in white chips of bits of the other graph. Is there really no way round it?

Comment: It's all about code organization. Structure your plot generation in either a self contained script or function. That way you can make a change, and easily rerun the whole thing and redraw it from scratch.

Comment: @ClattyCake Why do you need to delete a line?

Comment: Hi Ari, just trying to familiarise myself with R commands. I'm quite new to programming, though I've done osme before it's not been to a very high level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R plot undo line segment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131105/r-plot-undo-line-segment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick to erasing in R base is to redraw everything except what you want to erase in a new plot

so if you:

```
plot(x,y,main="X vs Y", xlab="X", ylab="Y")
lines(x,y,col="black",lty="dotted")
```

then decide that you dont want the line then you:

```
plot(x,y,main="X vs Y", xlab="X", ylab="Y")
```

Then if you want to erase everthing then you

```
plot.new()
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to delete a line you just delete the line command and rerun the rest of your commands.

You should think of your plot as your code.  You save the code because it's even more informative about what the plot is than the actual plot.  Unless you have a LOT of things to draw in your plot it's relatively trivial to just re-plot everything.  You may need to re-plot dozens of times until it's exactly what you want.  FYI, deep down, this is exactly what some GUI based graphing programs do when you tweak things (depends on what you tweak).  So, it's not like R is particularly special in this sense.

Alternatively, save the plot as a vector graphic (i.e. PDF), open in a compatible vector graphic drawing program (i.e. Illustrator), and tweak to your hearts content.