# Remove text box inserted into plot using locator in r

Tags: r, plot

How can I remove the last item (like a text box) inserted using locator? i.e.

```
plot(1:3)
text(locator(1),labels="oops wrong spot...remove me",cex=1,font=1)
```

Comment: I don't think you can. The general model for drawing things with R is that once something appears on the device, it's there until you wipe the entire device, or overwrite it.

Comment: as a hack, you could write over it with white text (or the background color, if it's not transparent)

Comment: If your workflow depends that strongly on manually annotating your graphs, you would probably be better off switching tools, to use an image editor to post-process them. Something like Inkscape or Photoshop will have more allowances for undoing mistakes.

Comment: True but I find the image quality reduces when running it through a secondary program...

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131105/r-plot-undo-line-segment , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569339/deleting-line-from-plot?lq=1

Comment: image quality shouldn't decrease when going through secondary programs if you are using the right (typically vector) graphics format etc., but it can admittedly be a little bit tricky/platform-dependent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can very easily implement something that will let you do this:

```
locator <- function(...) {
    assign('.last.plot', recordPlot(), envir=.GlobalEnv)
    graphics::locator(...)
}

undo <- function()
   if (exists('.last.plot')) replayPlot(.last.plot)

plot(1:3)
text(locator(1),labels="oops wrong spot...remove me",cex=1,font=1)
undo()
```

Comment: Nice! This is so helpful as now I don't have to play 'no room for error' games with my plots. Thanks!!!